# How can I set the Google Analytics User ID using ga.js instead of analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to set the User ID using ga.js.  I have found this reference for doing it with analytics.js here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id

But I have been unable to find any code samples to set the same 'userId' parameter in the ga.js syntax.

Is there an official way to do this?  Unfortunately, switching to analytics.js is not an option for us right now.

Answer (score 1):

The UserID feature is **only** available on Universal Analytics as indicated here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en and here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/.

**It's one of the new features that come with upgrading to UA.**

Hope this helps.